# slashbox alternative

Tags: tables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Diagonal lines in table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17745/diagonal-lines-in-table-cell)

Is there a better way to label both axes of a table at the same time rather than using slashbox?  It looks kind of ugly.

Answer (score 30):

### Edit

I wrote a new [`diagbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/diagbox/) package as a replacement of old `slashbox`. It is more modern that draw the diagonal lines via `pict2e` package, and easier to use:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{diagbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}\hline
\diagbox[width=10em]{Diag\\Column Head I}{Diag Column\\Head II}&
  Second & Third \\ \hline
& foo & bar \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Additional information can be found in [the document](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/diagbox/diagbox.pdf).

---

AFAIK, there are two packages for this diag cell in table. One is [`slashbox`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/slashbox.html), the other is [`makecell`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/makecell.html), which may produce better result sometimes. Here is an example of `\diaghead` in `makecell`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}\hline
\diaghead{\theadfont Diag ColumnmnHead II}%
  {Diag\\Column Head I}{Diag Column\\Head II}&
\thead{Second\\column}&\thead{Third\\column}\\ \hline
& foo & bar \\    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And it would be even better on screen if you use `pict2e` package together with `slashbox` or `makecell`.

Comment: copied from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11690/putting-latex-table-legend-in-a-x-y-style

Answer (score 17):

You are right that they do not look very nice. You can use two different alternatives. In  first one you can use a sub-heading, as the first example in the code below and the second one (which I prefer) is to assume that your reader is an intelligent human being and omit them altogether! By proper captioning you can also ensure that your message is clear.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{slashbox,booktabs,amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|l||*{5}{c|}}\hline
\backslashbox{Room}{Date}
&\makebox[3em]{5/31}&\makebox[3em]{6/1}&\makebox[3em]{6/2}
&\makebox[3em]{6/3}&\makebox[3em]{6/4}\\\hline\hline
Meeting Room &&&&&\\\hline
Auditorium &&&&&\\\hline
Seminar Room &&&&&\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
\toprule
\textbf{Date} &\makebox[3em]{5/31}&\makebox[3em]{6/1}&\makebox[3em]{6/2}
&\makebox[3em]{6/3}&\makebox[3em]{6/4}\\
\midrule
\textbf{Room} &&&&&\\
Meeting Room &&&&&\\
Auditorium &&&&&\\
Seminar Room &&&&&\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Room availability \textit{vs} dates.}
\end{table}


\bigskip

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
\toprule
~&\makebox[3em]{5/31}&\makebox[3em]{6/1}&\makebox[3em]{6/2}
&\makebox[3em]{6/3}&\makebox[3em]{6/4}\\
\midrule
Meeting Room &&&&&\\
Auditorium &&&&&\\
Seminar Room &&&&&\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Room availability \textit{vs} dates.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

that is a problem when the entries for `\backslashbox` are very small. Insert some spaces and everything will be fine and, by the way, always load pict2e which extends the default line segments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{slashbox,pict2e}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|r||*{5}{c|}}\hline
\backslashbox{Room~}{Date~~}
  & 5/31& 6/1 & 6/2 & 6/3 & 6/4 \\\hline
Meeting Room &&&&& \\\hline
Auditorium   &&&&& \\\hline
Seminar Room &&&&& \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]