# Putting LaTeX table legend in a "x\y" style

Tags: tables, labels, legend

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tables of numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7262/tables-of-numbers)

Is it possible to put a "x\y" style legend in one cell (maybe be made up of several cells) of a table? It would be great to make the 'x' slightly lower while the 'y' slight higher.

Please see the picture below for illustration:

[image: XY_style]

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! Note that it is unusual around here to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to have any greeting. A suggestion: Change your username to something more telling than "user2015".

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7262/tables-of-numbers, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9275/combined-header-cell-in-a-table and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9253/slashbox-alternative. Maybe one of the solutions to these questions is applicable to your case.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7262/tables-of-numbers provides a perfect solution --- i.e. \backslashbox in slashbox package. Thank you very much @Caramdir.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

AFAIK, there are two packages for this purpose. One is my [`diagbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/diagbox/) (replacement of old [`slashbox`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/slashbox.html)). The other is [`makecell`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/makecell.html). Here is an example of `\diaghead` in `makecell`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}

\section*{diagbox}

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}\hline
\theadfont\diagbox[width=11em]{Diag\\Column Head I}{Diag Column\\Head II}&
\thead{Second\\column}&\thead{Third\\column}\\    \hline
& foo & bar \\    \hline
\end{tabular}

\section*{makecell}

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}\hline
\diaghead{\theadfont Diag ColumnmnHead II}%
{Diag\\Column Head I}{Diag Column\\Head II}&
\thead{Second\\column}&\thead{Third\\column}\\    \hline
& foo & bar \\    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: maybe you could add the `makecell` answer to the duplicate question, so that we have all solutions in one place.

Comment: @Caramdir: Yes. But which one should I answer? I've no good idea.

Comment: Ok, I add this answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9253/slashbox-alternative/