# Diagonal tabular cell questions

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

My MWE is adapted from [How to diagonally divide a table cell … properly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89745/how-to-diagonally-divide-a-table-cell-properly).

Two questions:

1. I add an empiric rule of `0.71\baselineskip`, but why `0.71`?
2. Why `c=...` is not centered as the text below is?

**Edit** One ca see a simplified and corrected version here : [Optional argument problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175577/optional-argument-problem)

[image: output]

```
\documentclass[10pt,french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz,fourier}

\newcommand\diag[5]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{|m{#2}|}{\hskip-\tabcolsep
  $\vcenter{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0,anchor=south west,outer sep=0]
  \path[use as bounding box] (0,0) rectangle (#2+2\tabcolsep,\baselineskip);
  \node[minimum width={#2+2\tabcolsep-\pgflinewidth},
        minimum  height=\baselineskip+#3-\pgflinewidth] (box) {};
  \draw[line cap=round] (box.north west) -- (box.south east);
  \node[anchor=south west,align=left,inner sep=#1] at (box.south west) {#4};
  \node[anchor=north east,align=right,inner sep=#1] at (box.north east) {#5};
 \end{tikzpicture}}\rule{0pt}{.71\baselineskip+#3-\pgflinewidth}$\hskip-\tabcolsep}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{%
    |>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4.5cm}
    |*{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.5em}|}}\hline
\diag{\tabcolsep}{4.5cm}{3.4em}{Coefficient\\ de frottement $c$}{Vitesse $V$\\ (en km/h)}&50&90&110&20\\ \hline
$c=0,8$\newline route s\`eche, bitume neuf &&&&\\ \hline
$c=0,7$\newline route s\`eche, bitume moyen &&&&\\ \hline
$c=0,8$\newline route mouill\'ee, bitume moyen &&&&\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could `0.71` be an approximation to `1/\sqrt{2}=0.70710678...`?

Comment: @Mico As `\strut` definition is `\rule[-.3\baselineskip]{0pt}{\baselineskip}`, I thaught it came from hidden `\strut` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution with package `diagbox`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{diagbox,ragged2e}
\usepackage{fourier}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{%
    |>{\Centering}m{4.5cm}
    |*{4}{>{\Centering}m{2.5em}|}}\hline
\diagbox{\shortstack{Coefficient de\\ frottement $c$}}
        {\shortstack{\vphantom{Ä}Vitesse $V$\\(en km/h)}} & 50 & 90 & 110 & 20 \\ \hline
$c=0,8$\newline route s\`eche, bitume neuf &&&&\\ \hline
$c=0,7$\newline route s\`eche, bitume moyen &&&&\\ \hline
$c=0,8$\newline route mouill\'ee, bitume moyen &&&&\\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Use `\diag{\tabcolsep}{4.5cm}{0em}....` and in the `\diag`macro set `\rule{4pt}{0.71\baselineskip....}` then you'll see that it is the height of the current line (without a the depth). The entried are left and right aligned, see the optional arguments of `\node`: `align=...`. Change it to `align=center` and it will no more be left/right aligned.

Comment: @Herbet Thank you for your usefull answer, I learned of it. I still want to know the two points asked above.

Comment: see my edited answer

Comment: For the depth I agree with you, but for `align=...` it is not work. I speak about `c=...` in lines 2 to 4, there's no nodes here.

Comment: Ah I see, a misunderstanding. Load package ragged2e and then \Centering, as seen in my example.

Answer (score 1):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of the package `nicematrix` has its own command `\diagbox` to deal with that kind of problem.

```
\documentclass[10pt,french]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{fourier}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{w{c}{4.5cm}*{4}{w{c}{2.5em}}}[hvlines,cell-space-limits=3pt]
\rule{0pt}{1cm}
\diagbox{Coefficient \\ de frottement $c$}
        {Vitesse $V$\\(en km/h)} & 50 & 90 & 110 & 20 \\ 
\Block{}{$c=0,8$\\ route sèche, bitume neuf} \\
\Block{}{$c=0,7$\\ route sèche, bitume moyen} \\
\Block{}{$c=0,8$\\ route mouillée, bitume moyen} \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]