# As I done the line break inside the cell of the table, the vertical lines has disappeared or not showing up

Tags: tables

I've written the below code with the quote from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286146/how-to-diagonally-divide-a-table-cell-adaptation).

```
\documentclass[border=0.1cm]{article}

\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
    
      \begin{table}\centering\setlength\tabcolsep{3.5pt}\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
          \noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{%
            \begin{tabular}{|l|*{3}{c|}}
              \hline
              \diagbox[width=\dimexpr \textwidth/8+2\tabcolsep\relax, height=1cm,width=3cm]{ row  }{column }
             & smth1 & smth2 \\
              \hline
              smth3   & 1 & 2  \\  
              \hline
              smth4& 3 & 4 \\
              \hline
            \end{tabular}
          }
        \end{table}        

\end{document}
```

Got the below image from the above code.

[image]

As I done line break at the cell of smth3, the blank lines have appeared as shown in the below image.

How can I resolve this problem?

```
\documentclass[border=0.1cm]{article}

\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
    
      \begin{table}\centering\setlength\tabcolsep{3.5pt}\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
          \noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{%
            \begin{tabular}{|l|*{3}{c|}}
              \hline
              \diagbox[width=\dimexpr \textwidth/8+2\tabcolsep\relax, height=1cm,width=3cm]{ row  }{column }
             & smth1 & smth2 \\
              \hline
              smth3 \\ text at 2nd row of smth3  & 1 & 2  \\ % Added "\\ text at 2nd row of smth3" 
              \hline
              smth4& 3 & 4 \\
              \hline
            \end{tabular}
          }
        \end{table}        

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In the line containing `smth3` you must add the two `&&` before the end line macro ``\\``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=0.1cm]{article}

\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}\centering\setlength\tabcolsep{3.5pt}\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
        \noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{%
            \begin{tabular}{|l|*{3}{c|}}
                \hline
                \diagbox[width=\dimexpr \textwidth/8+2\tabcolsep\relax, height=1cm,width=4.2cm]{ row  }{column }
                & smth1 & smth2 \\
                \hline
                \makecell[l]{smth3 \\ text at 2nd row of smth3}  & 1 & 2  \\ % Added "\\ text at 2nd row of smth3" 
                \hline
                smth4& 3 & 4 \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        }
    \end{table}        
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use multirow given in  [How to use \multirow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73283/how-to-use-multirow)

Here is the complete code

```
\documentclass[border=0.1cm]{article}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
        \begin{table}\centering \setlength\tabcolsep{3.5pt}\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
          \noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{%
            \begin{tabular}{|l|*{3}{c|}}
              \hline
              \diagbox[width=\dimexpr \textwidth/8+2\tabcolsep\relax, height=1cm,width=3cm]{ row  }{column }
             & smth1 & smth2 \\
              \hline
              smith3 & \multirow{ 2}{*}{1}  & \multirow{ 2}{*}{2}   \\ % Added "\\ text at 2nd row of smth3" 
              text at 2nd row of smth3 &&\\
              \hline
              smth4& 3 & 4 \\
              \hline
            \end{tabular}
          }
        \end{table}        
\end{document}
```

[image]