# Why doesn't the diagonal line produced by \diagbox touch the table cell corners?

Tags: tables, diagbox

I was trying to use \diagbox, but It's not going from one corner to another corner in a cell (look on image). Anyone could help me? Please. Thanks.

[image]

```
\documentclass [a4paper,11pt] {article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{diagbox}

\usepackage [utf8] {inputenc}
\usepackage [portuges] {babel}
\usepackage {enumerate}
\usepackage {color}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage {setspace}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage {geometry}
\usepackage {fancyhdr}
\usepackage {graphicx}
\usepackage {url}
\usepackage {longtable}
\usepackage {rotating}
\usepackage {subfigure}
\usepackage[numbib,nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}

\sloppy

\geometry{left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}

\font\apre = phvrc scaled 1200

\newcommand{\traco}{ \vspace{-0.9cm}
\noindent\rule{16.6cm}{0.4pt}}


\setlength{\parskip}{5pt}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin {document}

\begin{figure} [!ht]
  \bfseries
  \mbox{
      \subfigure{
          \includegraphics [width=0.2\textwidth] {UTFPR.jpg}}\qquad
      \subfigure{
          \includegraphics [scale=0.6] {cabecalho.pdf}} \qquad
      \subfigure{
          \includegraphics [width=0.2\textwidth] {logo-DAINF-7_1.png}}
  }
\end{figure}

\begin{center}
\large{\textbf{Proposta de Trabalho de Conclusão de Curso}}
\end{center}\vspace{-0.3cm}

\tcboxfit[width=16.8cm,height=2.3cm,blank,
  borderline={1pt}{-4pt}{black},nobeforeafter,
  before=\noindent]{\normalsize\textbf{Título da Proposta: Estudo sobre constelações heterogêneas (diferentes) para detecção de canais.}\\
\textbf{Aluno: ...}\\
\textbf{Telefone: ...}\\
\textbf{E-mail: ...} \\
\textbf{Orientador: ...} }

\onehalfspacing

\section{Introdução}\traco

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1.7]{universe}
\caption{O universo}
\label{fig:universe}
\end{figure}

\section{Objetivos} \traco

\section{Metodologia} \traco
    
\section{Cronogama} \vspace{-0.9cm}
\noindent\rule{16.6cm}{0.4pt}

 

\begin{table}[hbt]
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{\diagbox[trim=l]{~}{~}} & \multicolumn{10}{c|}{2023} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{2024} \\
 & Mar & Abr & Mai & Jun & Jul & Ago & Set & Out & Nov & Dez & Jan & Fev \\ 
\hline\hline
Atividade 1 & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ \hline
Atividade 2 & ~ & ~ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ \hline
Atividade 3 & ~ & ~ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ \hline 
Atividade 4 & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ \hline
Atividade 5 & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & $\bullet$ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ \hline
Atividade 6 & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & $\bullet$ & ~ & ~ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Cronograma de atividades do projeto}
\label{tab:cronograma}
\end{table}


\section{Conclusão}

\citeonline{adams1995hitchhiker} diz que sempre acha que algo está fundamentalmente errado com o universo.


\bibliography{references} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to diagonally divide a table cell … properly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89745/how-to-diagonally-divide-a-table-cell-properly)

Comment: (or [Diagonal lines in table cell - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17745/diagonal-lines-in-table-cell), both has alternative solutions that allow diagonal lines at arbitrary slope)

Comment: Actually maybe that's not the issue, the issue is that your cell is wider so just pass a larger `width` value to the command, should just work.

Comment: Thanks everybody, the third comment solved my question. Thanks @user202729 for dedication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People, I only solved by using width parameter of \diagbox. Thanks @user202729.

```
\multirow{2}{*}{\diagbox[width=7em]{~}{~}} & \multicolumn{10}{c|}{2023} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{2024} \\
```