# Making advanced tables

Tags: tables, formatting

[image]

I am trying to generate tables like the one above I found in a textbook in LaTeX.

In particular I am trying to find a way to make that $\$ slash symbol in the left upper corner. It would also be great if there was a way to make the words read from the side. But i do not want to read 180 degrees.

Comment: I don't understand the part "a way to make the words read from the side". Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: have you checked out the [`slashbox` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/slashbox)?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, You know how to hav to tilt your head 180 degrees to read *Actual Temperature*? I want to rotate the two words by 180 degrees

Comment: Also see [Diagonally divided table cell](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7262), [Combined header cell in a table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9275), and [How to diagonally divide a table cell … properly?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89745). Please make sure to search the existing questions thoroughly before posting a question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possibility using TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{ 
table/.style={
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={rectangle,draw=black,text width=3em,align=center},
  text depth=1.25ex,
  text height=2.5ex,
  nodes in empty cells
},
row 1/.style={nodes={fill=green!10}},
column 1/.style={nodes={fill=green!10}}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix (mat) [table]
{
& 20  & 30 & 40 & 50 & 60 & 70 \\
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 & 83 \\
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 & 83 \\
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 & 83 \\
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 & 83 \\
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 & 83 \\
};
\draw (mat-1-1.north west) -- (mat-1-1.south east);
\node at ([xshift=-7pt,yshift=-4.5pt]mat-1-1) {$T$};
\node at ([xshift=7pt,yshift=4.5pt]mat-1-1) {$h$};
\node[rotate=90,anchor=south,font=\bfseries] at (mat.west) {Actual temperature ($^{\circ}$F)};
\node[anchor=south,font=\bfseries] at (mat.north) {Relative humidity (\%)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, with the text "Actual temperature (F)", placed horizontally:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{ 
table/.style={
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={rectangle,draw=black,text width=3em,align=center},
  text depth=1.25ex,
  text height=2.5ex,
  nodes in empty cells
},
row 1/.style={nodes={fill=green!10}},
column 1/.style={nodes={fill=green!10}}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix (mat) [table]
{
& 20  & 30 & 40 & 50 & 60 & 70 \\
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 & 83 \\
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 & 83 \\
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 & 83 \\
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 & 83 \\
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 & 83 \\
};
\draw (mat-1-1.north west) -- (mat-1-1.south east);
\node at ([xshift=-7pt,yshift=-4.5pt]mat-1-1) {$T$};
\node at ([xshift=7pt,yshift=4.5pt]mat-1-1) {$h$};
\node[anchor=east,font=\bfseries,align=center] at (mat.west) {Actual \\ temperature \\ ($^{\circ}$F)};
\node[anchor=south,font=\bfseries] at (mat.north) {Relative humidity (\%)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And here's a possibility using `slashbox` (personally, I find the results produced by `slashbox` to be of poor quality):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{slashbox}

\begin{document}

\noindent\parbox{2.2cm}{\bfseries\centering Actual \\ temperature \\ ($^{\circ}$F)}
{
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor{green!10}}c*{6}{|c}|}
\multicolumn{7}{c}{\bfseries Relative hunidity (\%)} \\
\hline
\rowcolor{green!10}\backslashbox{$T$}{$h$} & 20  & 30 & 40 & 50 & 60 & 70 \\
\hline
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 & 83 \\
\hline
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 & 83 \\
\hline
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 & 83 \\
\hline
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 & 83 \\
\hline
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 & 83 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to center the table, you can use a `table` environment (if you want to treat the object as a floating object), or a `minipage` (if no flotation is desired), and `\centering`:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\parbox{2.2cm}{\bfseries\centering Actual \\ temperature \\ ($^{\circ}$F)}
{
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor{green!10}}c*{6}{|c}|}
\multicolumn{7}{c}{\bfseries Relative hunidity (\%)} \\
\hline
\rowcolor{green!10}\backslashbox{$T$}{$h$} & 20  & 30 & 40 & 50 & 60 & 70 \\
\hline
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 & 83 \\
\hline
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 & 83 \\
\hline
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 & 83 \\
\hline
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 & 83 \\
\hline
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 & 83 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
\parbox{2.2cm}{\bfseries\centering Actual \\ temperature \\ ($^{\circ}$F)}
{
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor{green!10}}c*{6}{|c}|}
\multicolumn{7}{c}{\bfseries Relative hunidity (\%)} \\
\hline
\rowcolor{green!10}\backslashbox{$T$}{$h$} & 20  & 30 & 40 & 50 & 60 & 70 \\
\hline
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 & 83 \\
\hline
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 & 83 \\
\hline
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 & 83 \\
\hline
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 & 83 \\
\hline
80 & 78 & 79 & 80 & 81 & 82 & 83 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: I am not very familiar with Tikz. I use MacTeX

Comment: @jak TikZ is part of every major LaTeX distribution; in particular, TikZ is available in an updated MacTeX installation.

Comment: I am not very familiar with Tikz, but I changed the rotation to 180 and my text gets overlapped. How do I fix this

Comment: @jak How exactly do you want the text to appear? Did you see the second code of my answer?

Comment: Yes I saw your second code. You mirroed the words. I want to be able to see the words horizontally

Comment: @jak Ah, now I see. Let me do some changes.

Comment: @jak please see my updated answer. Is it something like that what you want?

Comment: Yes, but is it possible to do this with slash box? Because then I can start centring my table and do stuff with the TeX code that I am familiar with

Comment: @jak yes, it's possible; in some minutes I might add an answer using slashbox.

Comment: @jak please see my updated answer.

Comment: Hmmm thank you. I noticed that the text formatting prevents it from being centred. That is, I cannot centre the table without ruining the text.

Comment: @jak of course you can; are you going to use a `table` environment?

Comment: Yes, but I am up for anything that also works...

Comment: @jak please see my updated answer.