# label in subcaption and customize cell size of an array

Tags: captions, arrays, subcaption

Using the following code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\DeclareCaptionSubType*[arabic]{table}
\captionsetup[subtable]{labelformat=simple,labelsep=space}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{subtable}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
$\begin{array}{ | c | c | c | c | } \hline
\ast & \ast & \ast & \ast \\ \hline
\ast & \ast & \ast & \ast \\ \hline
\ast & \ast & \ast & \ast \\ \hline
\ast & \ast & \ast & \ast \\ \hline
\end{array}$
\subcaption{Subtable 1}
\label{lab1}
\end{subtable}
\begin{subtable}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
$\begin{array}{ | c | c | c | c | } \hline
\ast & \ast & \ast & \ast \\ \hline
\ast & \ast & \ast & \ast \\ \hline
\ast & \ast & \ast & \ast \\ \hline
\ast & \ast & \ast & \ast \\ \hline
\end{array}$
\subcaption{Subtable 1}
\label{lab2}
\end{subtable}
\caption{Sub Tables}
\label{lab3}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I can produce the below table and subtables. One question is how to use 1a, 1b as label (counter?), instead of 1.1, 1.2. [image: pic]

The second question is how to customize the cell size in an array? In the above example, each cell is an exact square, but if I type something inside, it become (not exact ) rectangle automatically. One can use `\begin{array}{ | p{1cm} | p{1cm} | }` to fix the cell width to 1cm, but I didn't find a way to fix cell height. Also, even one can fix the size, how to put the content in the center?

Final question is how to put a diagonal line or a cross in a cell? (I found a way which use TikZ, but if there is eaiser way? )

Comment: I searched for a while, it seems there is no direct way to assign the row height, like `p{width}` or `m{width}`. I can't believe it.....

Comment: Regarding the 1st question `\renewcommand\thesubtable{\thetable\alph{subtable}}` should do the job. Please also take a look at the section "References" I have added to the very recent version of the `subcaption` package documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked quite a few questions, and I'll try and answer them in order.

1. To change the sub-table labels, you can use

   ```
   \DeclareCaptionSubType*[alph]{table}
   ```
2. There are quite a few ways to change the vertical sizing of an `array`; if you load the `array` package, then you can use

   ```
   \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
   ```

   and change the `2` to whatever you would like. Alternatively you could use something like the `bigstrut` package, which provides the command `\bigstrut` to be used at the end of each line. You could also use something like `\parbox[c][3cm][t]{3cm}{ ...content...}` which would guarantee the cell size.
3. Finally, have a look at the following post to put a diagonal line in a table cell

   [Diagonal lines in table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17745/diagonal-lines-in-table-cell)

A complete MWE follows

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\DeclareCaptionSubType*[alph]{table}
\captionsetup[subtable]{labelformat=simple,labelsep=space}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{bigstrut}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{subtable}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
$\begin{array}{ | c | c | c | c | } \hline
 \parbox[c][3cm][b]{3cm}{$\ast$} & \ast & \ast & \ast \bigstrut\\ \hline
\ast & \ast & \ast & \ast \\ \hline
\ast & \ast & \ast & \ast \\ \hline
\ast & \ast & \ast & \ast \\ \hline
\end{array}$
\subcaption{Subtable 1}
\label{lab1}
\end{subtable}
\begin{subtable}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
$\begin{array}{ | c | c | c | c | } \hline
\ast & \ast & \ast & \ast \\ \hline
\ast & \ast & \ast & \ast \\ \hline
\ast & \ast & \ast & \ast \\ \hline
\ast & \ast & \ast & \ast \\ \hline
\end{array}$
\subcaption{Subtable 1}
\label{lab2}
\end{subtable}
\caption{Sub Tables}
\label{lab3}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

Following the comment, you could define a `\newcommand`

```
\newcommand{\mycell}[1]{\parbox[c][3cm][c]{3cm}{\centering #1}}
```

which can be used as (for example)

```
 \mycell{$\ast$}
```

and will center the contents vertically and horizontally

Comment: thanks. But I found neither the ways are good. Why there is no direct way to assign the row height? For column width, we can use `p{width}` to do this. Using `\arraystretch` and `\bigstrut`, we need to adjust several times to get equal width and height. Furthermore, if I use 'c' to center the content, after using `\arraystretch` it's no longer at the center.

Comment: @user565739 see my edited answer (MWE updated too)

Comment: thanks again. I like this way since in `\parbox`, one can type whatever he wants, although I have to type many `\parbox` if I need it for each entry in my array. Do you know how to put thing in the center in a \parbox? For example, in `\parbox[c][1cm][c]{1cm}{ $\ast$ }`, the `\ast` is not at the center. Or if I want to put `123`, then it's not at the center neither. I could get vertical center, but not horizontal center. (But if I use `\[  \ast \]` inside `\parbox`, I got horizontal center but not vertical center.....sigh)

Comment: @user565739 see my edit