# Centering vertically in table cell

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I'm new with LaTeX and I'm trying to make a table with the elements centered vertically and horizontally. I've searched for this question, it seems like most people were trying to do things a little more complicated than this, resulting in complicated answers I couldn't understand. The table below is already centered horizontally, but the elements are aligned to the top of the cells instead of the center. How do I fix this?

```
    \begin{tabular}{*{5}{|c}|}
        \hline
        $p$ & $q$ & $p \land q$ & $p \lor q$ & $p \to q$\\
        \hline
        T & T & T & T & T\\
        \hline
        T & F & F & T & F\\
        \hline
        F & T & F & T & T\\
        \hline
        F & F & F & F & T\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
```

Comment: I don't think there's an easy solution to align the rows to the centre. To see why this is usually not what you want, observe that in most tables you want to align the text in the rows by the base line.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen That type of alignment would be better than aligning to the top which is what's happening with this table. If that's simple, I'll take that for an answer.

Comment: I think the horizontal `\hline` commands are the cause of the misconception about the alignment. I'm posting a non-solution further on that shows the rows are aligned to the base line. Please note that I've removed the vertical lines in the `tabular` environment because the `booktabs` package doesn't like them. Personally, I'd remove all the `\midrule` commands as well, except for the first.

Comment: You should take a look at the `array` package and all comments in this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40581/centering-cells-of-a-tabular-column-using-m/40751 Thread, i think they might help you.

Comment: Have a look at [label in subcaption and customize cell size of an array](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36047/label-in-subcaption-and-customize-cell-size-of-an-array) in particular, the bit about `mycell`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The vertical skip from baseline to baseline within regular text is given by `\baselineskip`. Within `tabular`, this is `0pt` but it is still accessible as `\normalbaselineskip`. Using your example as reference, it is clear to see that the vertical baseline skip still holds when drawing a vertical `1pt` rule of height `\normalbaselineskip`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{|c}|}
  \hline
  $p$ & $q$ & $p \land q$ & $p \lor q$ & $p \to q$\\
  \hline
  T & T & T\smash{\rule{1pt}{\normalbaselineskip}} & T & T\\
  \hline
  T & F & F & T & F\\
  \hline
  F & T & $f$ & T & T\\
  \hline
  F & F & F & F & T\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

If you have a very particular table, like the one in your example, where baseline alignment may seem to be inadequate, you could play around with the addition of a vertical "strut" like in the following example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\begin{document}
\newlength{\mylen}\settowidth{\mylen}{$p \to q$}% Widest element
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash\rule{0pt}{1.05em}}m{\mylen}}|}
  \hline
  $p$ & $q$ & $p \land q$ & $p \lor q$ & $p \to q$\\ 
  \hline
  T & T & T & T & T\\
  \hline
  T & F & F & T & F\\
  \hline
  F & T & F & T & T\\
  \hline
  F & F & F & F & T\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Using the [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array), it allows you to insert `<stuff>` before every table column entry using `>{<stuff>}`. Using the `m{<width>}` column specification, I've fixed the column widths (I think it looks cleaner that way) and reverted back to the centering supplied by `c`-columns.

Although this may be a moot point based on personal preference, consider using the [`booktabs` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) to typeset tables:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\begin{document}
\newlength{\mylen}\settowidth{\mylen}{$p \to q$}% Widest element
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\mylen}}}
  \toprule
  $p$ & $q$ & $p \land q$ & $p \lor q$ & $p \to q$ \\ 
  \midrule
  T & T & T & T & T \\
  T & F & F & T & F \\
  F & T & F & T & T \\
  F & F & F & F & T \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the result I was looking for. However, I don't understand what \arraybackslash does. Could you explain that?

Comment: @gsingh2011: The `array` package allows for column specifications to include `>` and `<` for inclusion of stuff before/after a column entry. However, in doing so, it also modifies the traditional `\\` command for proceeding to a new line. `\arraybackslash` restores this traditional use.