# How to create transportation table like this

Tags: tables, math-table

[image]

How to create transportation table like this table?

Comment: You can start with [How to make a transportation tableau](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83713/how-to-make-a-transportation-tableau) and adapt to your needs. If you get stuck, post the MWE you got at and state the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go for simple `tabular` solution, then the following MWE will show how to do this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\def\Mc[#1]#2#3{\multicolumn{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\def\mc#1#2{\multicolumn{1}{#1}{#2}}

\extrarowheight=6pt
\begin{tabular}{c|cc|cc|cc|cc|cc|c}
\mc{c}{}& \Mc[2]{c}{1} & \Mc[2]{c}{2} & \Mc[2]{c}{$\cdots$} & \Mc[2]{c}{$\cdots$} & \Mc[2]{c}{$n$} & Supply \\[6pt]\cline{2-11}
  1     & \mc{c|}{$x_{11}$} &&  \mc{c|}{$x_{12}$} && \mc{c|}{$\cdots$} && \mc{c|}{$\cdots$} && \mc{c|}{$x_{1n}$} && $a_1$\\[6pt]\cline{2-2}\cline{4-4}\cline{6-6}\cline{8-8}\cline{10-10}
        && \mc{c|}{$c_{11}$} && \mc{c|}{$c_{12}$} && \mc{c|}{$\cdots$} && \mc{c|}{$\cdots$} && \mc{c|}{$c_{1n}$} & \\[6pt]\cline{2-11}
  2     & \mc{c|}{$x_{21}$} &&  \mc{c|}{$x_{22}$} && \mc{c|}{$\cdots$} && \mc{c|}{$\cdots$} && \mc{c|}{$x_{2n}$} && $a_2$\\[6pt]\cline{2-2}\cline{4-4}\cline{6-6}\cline{8-8}\cline{10-10}
        && \mc{c|}{$c_{21}$} && \mc{c|}{$c_{22}$} && \mc{c|}{$\cdots$} && \mc{c|}{$\cdots$} && \mc{c|}{$c_{2n}$} & \\[6pt]\cline{2-11}
  3     & \mc{c|}{$\cdots$} &&  \mc{c|}{$\cdots$} && \mc{c|}{$\cdots$} && \mc{c|}{$\cdots$} && \mc{c|}{$\cdots$} && $a_3$\\[6pt]\cline{2-2}\cline{4-4}\cline{6-6}\cline{8-8}\cline{10-10}
        && \mc{c|}{$\cdots$} && \mc{c|}{$\cdots$} && \mc{c|}{$\cdots$} && \mc{c|}{$\cdots$} && \mc{c|}{$\cdots$} & \\[6pt]\cline{2-11}
$\cdot$ & \mc{c|}{$\cdots$} &&  \mc{c|}{$\cdots$} && \mc{c|}{$\cdots$} && \mc{c|}{$\cdots$} && \mc{c|}{$\cdots$} && $\cdot$\\[6pt]\cline{2-2}\cline{4-4}\cline{6-6}\cline{8-8}\cline{10-10}
$\cdot$ && \mc{c|}{$\cdots$} && \mc{c|}{$\cdots$} && \mc{c|}{$\cdots$} && \mc{c|}{$\cdots$} && \mc{c|}{$\cdots$} &  $\cdot$\\[6pt]\cline{2-11}
$\cdot$ & \mc{c|}{$x_{m1}$} &&  \mc{c|}{$x_{m2}$} && \mc{c|}{$\cdots$} && \mc{c|}{$\cdots$} && \mc{c|}{$x_{mn}$} && $\cdot$\\[6pt]\cline{2-2}\cline{4-4}\cline{6-6}\cline{8-8}\cline{10-10}
$m$     && \mc{c|}{$c_{m1}$} && \mc{c|}{$x_{m2}$} && \mc{c|}{$\cdots$} && \mc{c|}{$\cdots$} && \mc{c|}{$c_{mn}$} & $a_{m}$\\[6pt]\cline{2-11}
\mc{c}{Demand}& \Mc[2]{c}{$b_1$} & \Mc[2]{c}{$b_2$} & \Mc[2]{c}{$\cdots$} & \Mc[2]{c}{$\cdots$} & \Mc[2]{c}{$b_n$} &  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with a `{tabular}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for the command \text

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\cc}[2]
 {
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{cc}
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$#1$}&\kern1.5em\\\cline{1-1}\kern2.2em&$#2$
  \end{tabular}
  \endgroup
 }
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{$#1$}}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}

\begin{tabular}{>{$}c<{$}|c|c|c|c|c|>{$}c<{$}}
\mc{}  & \mc{1} & \mc{2} & \mc{\cdots} & \mc{\cdots} & \mc{n} & \text{Supply} \\
\cline{2-6}
1 & \cc{x_{11}}{c_{11}} & \cc{x_{12}}{c_{12}} & \cc{\cdots}{\cdots} & \cc{\cdots}{\cdots} & \cc{x_{1n}}{c_{1n}} & a_1\\
\cline{2-6}
2 & \cc{x_{21}}{c_{21}} & \cc{x_{22}}{c_{22}} & \cc{\cdots}{\cdots} & \cc{\cdots}{\cdots} & \cc{x_{2n}}{c_{2n}} & a_2\\
\cline{2-6}
3 & \cc{\cdots}{\cdots} & \cc{\cdots}{\cdots} & \cc{\cdots}{\cdots} & \cc{\cdots}{\cdots} & \cc{\cdots}{\cdots} & a_3\\
\cline{2-6}
  & \cc{\cdots}{\cdots} & \cc{\cdots}{\cdots} & \cc{\cdots}{\cdots} & \cc{\cdots}{\cdots} & \cc{\cdots}{\cdots} \\
\cline{2-6}
m & \cc{x_{m1}}{c_{m1}} & \cc{x_{m2}}{c_{m2}} & \cc{\cdots}{\cdots} & \cc{\cdots}{\cdots} & \cc{x_{mn}}{c_{mn}} & a_m\\
\cline{2-6}
\mc{\text{Demand}} & \mc{b_1} & \mc{b_2} & \mc{\cdots} & \mc{\cdots} & \mc{b_n} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]