# How to create transportation table with long text in it

Tags: tables, longtable, fit

Can anyone help me to improve this transportation table so that it fits between the sentences in it and the size of the table?

[image]

It should be like this:

[image: Desired table form]

This is the latex coding for the transportation table. [Reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83713/how-to-make-a-transportation-tableau). Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand{\STAB}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

\newcolumntype{C}{@{}c@{}}
\newcommand{\bottombox}[1]{\makebox[1em][r]{#1}\hspace*{\tabcolsep}\hspace*{1em}}%
\newcommand{\innerbox}[2]{%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{c|c}
        \rule{1em}{0pt}\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{1ex} & \makebox[1em]{#2} \\\cline{2-2}
        \multicolumn{2}{r}{{#1}\hspace*{1\tabcolsep}\hspace*{1em}\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{1ex}}
\end{tabular}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table} [h]
        \centering
        \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}
        {\begin{tabular}{|c|c|C|C|C|c|}
                \hline
                \multicolumn{2}{|c}{\multirow{2}{*}{From $ \backslash $ To}} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Destinations} & \multirow{2}{*}{Supply} \\ \cline{3-5}
                \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & Sales Outlet H & Sales Outlet I & Sales Outlet J & \\ \hline
                \multirow{3}{*}{\STAB{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Sources}}} & Warehouse A & \innerbox{}{\$(6,8,10,12)} & \innerbox{}{\$(5,7,9,11)} & \innerbox{}{\$(2,4,6,8)} & (15,20,30,35) \\ \cline{2-6}
                & Warehouse B & \innerbox{}{\$(3,5,7,9)} & \innerbox{}{\$(5,7,9,11)} & \innerbox{}{\$(1,3,5,7)} & (25,30,40,45) \\ \cline{2-6}
                & Warehouse C & \innerbox{}{\$(4,6,8,10)} & \innerbox{}{\$(3,5,7,9)} & \innerbox{}{\$(6,8,10,12)} & (30,35,45,50) \\ \hline
                \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Demand} & (15,25,35,45) & (10,20,30,40) & (30,40,50,60) & \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it fits between the sentences in it and the size of the table?" Which sentences? And what does "and the size of the table" mean? Could you give a picture of what you actually want, maybe a hand drawing that you scan?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to explain about that. But now I've fixed my question. Thank you in advance for your response. @PietervanOostrum

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want all the inner boxes to have the same width, as your picture shows. Howver this is quite hard (although not impossible) to do in LaTeX. It would two runs. So I chose the easy way. I have a length `\innerboxwidth` for this. You must initialize it to the width of the widest entry, as I have done in my solution.

By the way, I changed the `\multirow` for `Sources` to 5 because that centers it better.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\STAB}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

\newcolumntype{C}{@{}c@{}}
\newcommand{\bottombox}[1]{\makebox[1em][r]{#1}\hspace*{\tabcolsep}\hspace*{1em}}%
\newlength{\innerboxwidth}
\settowidth{\innerboxwidth}{\$(6,8,10,12)}% widest entry
\newcommand{\innerbox}[2]{%
    \begin{tabular}[c]{c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\innerboxwidth}}
        \rule{1em}{0pt} & {#2} \\\cline{2-2}
        \multicolumn{2}{r}{{#1}\hspace*{1\tabcolsep}\hspace*{1em}\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{1ex}}
\end{tabular}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table} [h]
        \centering
        \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}
        {\begin{tabular}{|c|c|C|C|C|c|}
                \hline
                \multicolumn{2}{|c}{\multirow{2}{*}{From $ \backslash $ To}} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Destinations} & \multirow{2}{*}{Supply} \\ \cline{3-5}
                \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & Sales Outlet H & Sales Outlet I & Sales Outlet J & \\ \hline
                \multirow{5}{*}{\STAB{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Sources}}} & Warehouse A & \innerbox{}{\$(6,8,10,12)} & \innerbox{}{\$(5,7,9,11)} & \innerbox{}{\$(2,4,6,8)} & (15,20,30,35) \\ \cline{2-6}
                & Warehouse B & \innerbox{}{\$(3,5,7,9)} & \innerbox{}{\$(5,7,9,11)} & \innerbox{}{\$(1,3,5,7)} & (25,30,40,45) \\ \cline{2-6}
                & Warehouse C & \innerbox{}{\$(4,6,8,10)} & \innerbox{}{\$(3,5,7,9)} & \innerbox{}{\$(6,8,10,12)} & (30,35,45,50) \\ \hline
                \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Demand} & (15,25,35,45) & (10,20,30,40) & (30,40,50,60) & \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution has been very helpful for solving my problem. Thank you very much!