# How to make this following table?

Tags: tables

I don't know how to make the diagonal line at the top left.

[image]

Comment: Could you please add a minimal (working) example of your efforts, if any? It would help solvers a lot to actually start working on it.

Comment: When you [search in tex.sx](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=diagonal+line+first+row+table) the second relevant Q [Slashbox with tables: Adjusting the diagonal separator for multiple rows](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114174/15717) and it's Linked Q's on right may be what you are looking for ?