# Split a tabularx cell at its diagonal when the X column specification is used?

Tags: tables, tabularx

How do I split a cell diagonally, when I'm using `tabularx` with `X` column, i.e. `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X}`?

I've seen many answers on this topic on TeX.SE, but none of them are applicable to cells with a fluid width (X column).

I've currently solved my problem by using the [`diagbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/diagbox) package with a hard-coded width (found through trial-and-error). However, I would like to know how to solve it properly, i.e. a way to achieve the diagonal split without knowing the dimensions of the cell in advance.

This is my current code, demonstrating the visually desired result, achieved by hard-coding the width of the `backslashbox`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|c|c|c|}
  \hline
    \backslashbox[92mm]{Task}{Question} & 1 & 2 & 3\\
  \hline
    What? & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
  \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: [Diagonal lines in table cell](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17745/5764) has some alternatives using of [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|c|c|c|}
  \hline
    \backslashbox[\dimexpr\linewidth+2\tabcolsep]{Task}{Question} & 1 & 2 & 3\\
  \hline
    What? & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
  \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works! Can you explain the `\dimexpr\linewidth+2\tabcolsep` part, preferably with references to documentation?

Comment: Instead of `\linewidth` you can also use `\hsize`.

Comment: @RobW: _every_ cell has on the left and right an additional width of `\tabcolsep` which is by default set to `6pt`