# Clashing multirow with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, multirow

In order to get a diagonal line in a cell, I picked up a piece of code from [Diagonal lines in table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17745/diagonal-lines-in-table-cell)

The code adapted to my situation works fine until I decide to use multirow.

Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\diag[4]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{p{#2}|}{\hskip-\tabcolsep
  $\vcenter{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0,anchor=south west,inner sep=#1]
  \path[use as bounding box] (0,0) rectangle (#2+2\tabcolsep,\baselineskip);
  \node[minimum width={#2+2\tabcolsep},minimum height=\baselineskip+\extrarowheight] (box) {};
  \draw (box.north west) -- (box.south east);
  \node[anchor=south west] at (box.south west) {#3};
  \node[anchor=north east] at (box.north east) {#4};
 \end{tikzpicture}}$\hskip-\tabcolsep}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{\diag{.1em}{.5cm}{$a$}{$i$}}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{A}\\\cline{2-2}
    &1\\
  \end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

This produces an error message,

```
 ! Misplaced \omit. \multispan ->\omit 
                    \@multispan  l.20 ...ultirow{2}{*}{\diag{.1em}{.5cm}{$a$}{$i$}}
                                                   &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{A}\\\...
```

If I omit the `\multirow` part this works fine.

Comment: Use of [diagbox](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/diagbox) was found to be a better option. This also did not clash with multirow.

Comment: The problem here lies in using a multicolumn inside a multirow. This asks for all kinds of problems, prompting the "Misplaced \omit" error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

As noted in comments you can't use `\multicolumn` here however as it is only spanning 1 cell, you don't need `\multicolum` and can simply use a `\parbox`.

The picture was generating a 12pt overfull box warning as `2\tabcolsep` was accounted for twice so I removed the inner addition of this ammount.

The `A` was in a multicolumn{2} so I put the `1` in to match, otherwise things didn't line up.

The code needed `array` package adding as you'd used `\extrarowheight` which is defined by that package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow,array}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\diag[4]{%
%  \multicolumn{1}{p{#2}|}
  \parbox[t]{#2}%
  {\hskip-\tabcolsep
  $\vcenter{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0,anchor=south west,inner sep=#1]
  \path[use as bounding box] (0,0) rectangle (#2,\baselineskip);
  \node[minimum width={#2+2\tabcolsep},minimum height=\baselineskip+\extrarowheight] (box) {};
  \draw (box.north west) -- (box.south east);
  \node[anchor=south west] at (box.south west) {#3};
  \node[anchor=north east] at (box.north east) {#4};
 \end{tikzpicture}}$\hskip-\tabcolsep}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{\diag{.1em}{.5cm}{$a$}{$i$}}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{A}\\\cline{2-3}
    &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{1}\\
  \end{tabular}


\end{document}
```