# Strike out a table cell

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I'm trying to strike out cells in a table, **without** specifying the cell width. To do so, I looked at the code of `colortbl` as this seems to a very decent job with filling cells.

Now I played around with all those `\@tempdim` but without any success. Honestly I have no idea what I'm doing.

> [image]

If possible, I'd like to get rid of `tikz`.

## What I have tried so far

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{tikz,colortbl}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\notableentry{%
    \@tempdima\wd\z@
    \advance\@tempdima\@tempdimb
    \advance\@tempdima\@tempdimc
    \tikz[remember picture]{\coordinate (X) at (-.5\tabcolsep-\@tempdima-\@tempdimb-\@tempdimc,-1.1\tabcolsep);}
    \hskip\@tempdima\@plus 1fill
    \kern-\tabcolsep
    \hskip-\wd\z@ \@plus -1fill
    \tikz[remember picture]{\coordinate (Y) at (.5\tabcolsep+\@tempdima+\@tempdimb,\@tempdima-.25\tabcolsep);}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\LARGE
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    alghreaiog & bghsah \\
    \hline
    cagja & \notableentry \\
    \hline
    \cellcolor{blue} & edkhaklgjaj \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{%
    \draw[red] (X) -- (Y);
    \draw[red] (X |- Y) -- (Y |- X);
}

\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|p{3cm}|}
    \hline
    alghreaiog & bghsah \\
    \hline
    cagja\par bla & \notableentry \\
    \hline
    \cellcolor{blue} & edkhaklgjaj \par xyz \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{%
    \draw[red] (X) -- (Y);
    \draw[red] (X |- Y) -- (Y |- X);
}
\end{document}
```

## Output

It seems to work for `c` columns, but fails for all other purposes, while `\cellcolor` always works.

> [image]

Comment: does it have to be a cross (which is a bit harder) or can it be a horizontal line (which you can do directly with colortbl)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle A cross is desirable (...my supervisor, etc...), but I will also accept an answer (and reward it with a bounty) featuring a horizontal line, if you explain, why a cross is not possible.

Comment: a cross is possible, but more likely to need tikz (or at least some back end support)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The following example uses package `zref-savepos` to get the positions of the cell. `\vadjust pre` (a newer feature invented by pdfTeX and also available in LuaTeX and XeTeX) puts the position marker right above the current cell and `\vadjust` puts the marker below.

`\notableentry` uses `\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}|}` to get the full cell width without `\tabcolsep` spacings. `\hspace{0pt plus 1filll}` is used to override the `c` specifier to get a position marker to the left and right of the cell.

The label names for the position markers (`\zsavepos`) are automatically generated with the help of counter `NoTableEntry`.

Finally the coordinates of the cell's bounding box are calculated and the cross drawn via `tikz`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{tikz,colortbl}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}

\newcounter{NoTableEntry}
\renewcommand*{\theNoTableEntry}{NTE-\the\value{NoTableEntry}}

\newcommand*{\notableentry}{%
  \multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}|}{%
    \stepcounter{NoTableEntry}%
    \vadjust pre{\zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry t}}% top
    \vadjust{\zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry b}}% bottom
    \zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry l}% left
    \hspace{0pt plus 1filll}%
    \zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry r}% right
    \tikz[overlay]{%
      \draw[red]
        let
          \n{llx}={\zposx{\theNoTableEntry l}sp-\zposx{\theNoTableEntry r}sp},
          \n{urx}={0},
          \n{lly}={\zposy{\theNoTableEntry b}sp-\zposy{\theNoTableEntry r}sp},
          \n{ury}={\zposy{\theNoTableEntry t}sp-\zposy{\theNoTableEntry r}sp}
        in
        (\n{llx}, \n{lly}) -- (\n{urx}, \n{ury})
        (\n{llx}, \n{ury}) -- (\n{urx}, \n{lly})
      ;
    }% 
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\LARGE
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    alghreaiog & bghsah \\
    \hline
    cagja & \notableentry \\
    \hline
    \cellcolor{blue} & edkhaklgjaj \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|p{3cm}|}
    \hline
    alghreaiog & bghsah \\
    \hline
    cagja\par bla & \notableentry \\
    \hline
    \cellcolor{blue} & edkhaklgjaj \par xyz \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Restriction to package `pgf`

The following modification restricts the drawing to the low level package `pgf` instead of using the front-end package `tikz`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}

\newcounter{NoTableEntry}
\renewcommand*{\theNoTableEntry}{NTE-\the\value{NoTableEntry}}

\newcommand*{\notableentry}{%
  \multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}|}{%
    \stepcounter{NoTableEntry}%
    \vadjust pre{\zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry t}}% top
    \vadjust{\zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry b}}% bottom
    \zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry l}% left
    %
    \begin{pgfpicture}%
      \pgfsetlinewidth{.4pt}%
      \pgfsetstrokecolor{red}%
      \edef\llx{0sp}%
      \edef\urx{%
        \the\numexpr
          \zposx{\theNoTableEntry r}%
          -\zposx{\theNoTableEntry l}%
        \relax sp%
      }%
      \edef\lly{%
        \the\numexpr
          \zposy{\theNoTableEntry b}%
          -\zposy{\theNoTableEntry l}%
        \relax sp%
      }%
      \edef\ury{%
        \the\numexpr
          \zposy{\theNoTableEntry t}%
          -\zposy{\theNoTableEntry l}%
        \relax sp%
      }%
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\llx}{\lly}}%
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\urx}{\ury}}%
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\llx}{\ury}}%
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\urx}{\lly}}%
      \pgfusepath{stroke}%
      \pgfresetboundingbox
    \end{pgfpicture}%
    %
    \hspace{0pt plus 1filll}%
    \zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry r}% right
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\LARGE
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    alghreaiog & bghsah \\
    \hline
    cagja & \notableentry \\
    \hline
    \cellcolor{blue} & edkhaklgjaj \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|p{3cm}|}
    \hline
    alghreaiog & bghsah \\
    \hline
    cagja\par bla & \notableentry \\
    \hline
    \cellcolor{blue} & edkhaklgjaj \par xyz \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Without `pgf`

The next solution uses `\rotatebox` to rotate a rule with the length of the hypotenuse/diagonal and `\reflectbox` to get the other diagonal of the cross.
The calculations of the length of the hypotenuse and the rotation angle are done via package `l3fp`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse, l3fp}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \NTECalcHypotenuse } { m m } {
  \fp_to_int:n { sqrt ( #1 * #1 + #2 * #2 ) - 0.5 }
}
\NewDocumentCommand { \NTECalcAngle } { m m } {
  \fp_to_decimal:n { atand ( #1 / #2 ) }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcounter{NoTableEntry}
\renewcommand*{\theNoTableEntry}{NTE-\the\value{NoTableEntry}}

\newcommand*{\notableentry}{%
  \multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}|}{%
    \stepcounter{NoTableEntry}%
    \vadjust pre{\zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry t}}% top
    \vadjust{\zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry b}}% bottom
    \zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry l}% left
    %
    \sbox0{%
      \color{red}%
      \edef\llx{0}%
      \edef\urx{%
        \the\numexpr
          \zposx{\theNoTableEntry r}%
          -\zposx{\theNoTableEntry l}%
        \relax
      }%
      \edef\lly{%
        \the\numexpr
          \zposy{\theNoTableEntry b}%
          -\zposy{\theNoTableEntry l}%
        \relax
      }%
      \edef\ury{%
        \the\numexpr
          \zposy{\theNoTableEntry t}%
          -\zposy{\theNoTableEntry l}%
        \relax
      }%
      \edef\w{\the\numexpr\urx-\llx\relax}%
      \edef\h{\the\numexpr\ury-\lly\relax}%
      \ifnum\w=0 %
      \else
        \setbox0=\hbox{%
          \edef\angle{\romannumeral-`x\NTECalcAngle{\h}{\w}}%
          \raisebox{\the\numexpr\zposy{\theNoTableEntry b}%
            -\zposy{\theNoTableEntry l}\relax sp%
          }{%
            \rotatebox{\angle}{%
              \vrule width\NTECalcHypotenuse{\h}{\w}sp height.2pt depth.2pt%
            }%
          }%
        }%
        \rlap{\unhcopy0}%
        \reflectbox{\unhcopy0}%
      \fi
    }%
    \wd0=0pt %
    \ht0=0pt %
    \dp0=0pt %
    \copy0 %
    %
    \hspace{0pt plus 1filll}%
    \zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry r}% right
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\LARGE
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    alghreaiog & bghsah \\
    \hline
    cagja & \notableentry \\
    \hline
    \cellcolor{blue} & edkhaklgjaj \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|p{3cm}|}
    \hline
    alghreaiog & bghsah \\
    \hline
    cagja\par bla & \notableentry \\
    \hline
    \cellcolor{blue} & edkhaklgjaj \par xyz \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### With `pict2e`

Package `pict2e` allows arbitrary real numbers in the range [-16383, 16383] for the slope arguments of `\line` in parentheses. Therefore the example uses `1pt` as `\unitlength` and recalculate the numbers of the `\pdfsavepos` feature that are given with unit `sp` to `pt`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\usepackage{pict2e}
%\usepackage{picture}

\newcounter{NoTableEntry}
\renewcommand*{\theNoTableEntry}{NTE-\the\value{NoTableEntry}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\notableentry}{%
  \multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}|}{%
    \stepcounter{NoTableEntry}%
    \vadjust pre{\zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry t}}% top
    \vadjust{\zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry b}}% bottom
    \zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry l}% left
    %
    \raisebox{%
      \dimexpr\zposy{\theNoTableEntry b}sp
      -\zposy{\theNoTableEntry l}sp\relax
    }[0pt][0pt]{%
      \color{red}% 
      \setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}%
      \edef\w{%
        \strip@pt\dimexpr\zposx{\theNoTableEntry r}sp%
        -\zposx{\theNoTableEntry l}sp\relax
      }% 
      \edef\h{%
        \strip@pt\dimexpr\zposy{\theNoTableEntry t}sp%
        -\zposy{\theNoTableEntry b}sp\relax
      }%
      \ifdim\w pt=0pt % prevent error in first run for \line(0,0)
      \else
        \begin{picture}(0,0)%
          % the arguments of `\line` needs to be expanded,
          % because `pict2e' needs to see the decimal dot 
          \edef\x{%
            \noexpand\put(0,0){\noexpand\line(\w,\h){\w}}%  
            \noexpand\put(0,\h){\noexpand\line(\w,-\h){\w}}%
          }\x
        \end{picture}%
      \fi
    }%
    \hspace{0pt plus 1filll}%
    \zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry r}% right
  }%
}   

\begin{document}
\LARGE
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    alghreaiog & bghsah \\
    \hline
    cagja & \notableentry \\
    \hline
    \cellcolor{blue} & edkhaklgjaj \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|p{3cm}|}
    \hline
    alghreaiog & bghsah \\
    \hline
    cagja\par bla & \notableentry \\
    \hline
    \cellcolor{blue} & edkhaklgjaj \par xyz \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Variant with `\notableentry` inside `\multicolumn`

In this variant, `\notableentry` is used inside `\multicolumn` with `c` as column specifier. That allows more flexibility regarding the vertical lines and the number of columns, which are covered by the cross.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\usepackage{pict2e}
%\usepackage{picture}

\newcounter{NoTableEntry}
\renewcommand*{\theNoTableEntry}{NTE-\the\value{NoTableEntry}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\notableentry}{%
  \kern-\tabcolsep
  \stepcounter{NoTableEntry}%
  \vadjust pre{\zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry t}}% top
  \vadjust{\zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry b}}% bottom
  \zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry l}% left
  %
  \raisebox{%
    \dimexpr\zposy{\theNoTableEntry b}sp
    -\zposy{\theNoTableEntry l}sp\relax
  }[0pt][0pt]{%
    \color{red}% 
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}%
    \edef\w{%
      \strip@pt\dimexpr\zposx{\theNoTableEntry r}sp%
      -\zposx{\theNoTableEntry l}sp\relax
    }% 
    \edef\h{%
      \strip@pt\dimexpr\zposy{\theNoTableEntry t}sp%
      -\zposy{\theNoTableEntry b}sp\relax
    }%
    \ifdim\w pt=0pt % prevent error in first run for \line(0,0)
    \else
      \begin{picture}(0,0)%
        % the arguments of `\line` needs to be expanded,
        % because `pict2e' needs to see the decimal dot 
        \edef\x{%
          \noexpand\put(0,0){\noexpand\line(\w,\h){\w}}%  
          \noexpand\put(0,\h){\noexpand\line(\w,-\h){\w}}%
        }\x
      \end{picture}%
    \fi
  }%
  \hspace{0pt plus 1filll}%
  \zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry r}% right
  \kern-\tabcolsep
}   

\begin{document}
\LARGE
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    alghreaiog & bghsah \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\notableentry} \\
    \hline
    \cellcolor{blue} & edkhaklgjaj \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|p{3cm}|}
    \hline
    alghreaiog & bghsah \\
    \hline
    cagja\par bla & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\notableentry} \\
    \hline
    \cellcolor{blue} & edkhaklgjaj \par xyz \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\notableentry} & asdf \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: +1 for `pre` I'd forgotten about that:-)

Comment: Magnificent! You will get your bounty in 2 days. Would it be possible to draw the cross using only LaTeX's `picture`? I don't know if it can do overlay.

Comment: @HenriMenke: LaTeX's `picture` environment only provides lines (`\line`) with a quite limited set of slopes.

Comment: but there is a package called `pict2e` ...

Comment: @Herbert: Thanks. Now the answer also contains a version for `pict2e`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Would it be possible to modify your answer in such a way that `\notableentry` can be used inside a `\multicolumn`?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: You mean in a way as column specification that would allow the cross covering more than one column?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Yes; to be able to write something like `\multicolumn{3}{c}{\notableentry}` and have the cross span the three columns.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I have added a variant of `\notableentry`, which is used inside `\multicolumn`.

Comment: Note that as it stands, if the table spans multiple pages and there are fixed top rows (carried along to each page) and your macro is executed within a fixed row, then warnings like **"Label `NTE-2t' multiply defined."** will show up. (NTE-21, NTE-2r, NTE-2b)

Comment: @JonathanKomar Package `longtable` uses the same fixed box for the header or footer rows. Package `supertabular` and friends use a macro-base approach and might therefore work.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Is this also possible to adjust for _multirow_? I found this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365620/crossing-out-multirow-multicolumn-cells but it's not really working..

Comment: @EmeraJade Not really, `multirow` has no idea about the real cells it covers. It just makes a guess about a row height, but this is too imprecise for the exact cross discussed here.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I have tried to implement any of these solutions within the tabularray tables and I cannot seem to get it to work (best I've gotten is a straight red line). Should I create a new question specific for it? It doesn't support multicolumn.

Comment: @JM, yes create a new question, because your problem seems to be specific to the `tabulararray` tables.

Answer (score 7):

`colortbl` uses `\leaders` with `\vrule` to add the panel, normally the `\vrule` extends to the full height/depth of the containing box which is why it fills the cell, however if you specify a fixed height and depth then you get a horizontal line. note that you can't see at the TeX macro layer what the extent of the box is, that is resolved later in the alignment code in TeX's internals. So even though `\vrule` draws a line from top to bottom, you don't know where the "top" is so you can't draw a cross without using something like `\pdfsavepos` which is what the tikz remember stuff is doing. Then of course even if you know the coordinates you need some back end code to draw a line of a given slope. (You don't need the whole of tikz, but you need something)

As it happens, I developed `color` and `colortbl` on a monochrome screen and since black-on-black is a bit hard to read There is a built in option to restrict colortbl to a thin horizontal line. (It would be easy to not use this option all the time and just have a command that locally uses this debug version but:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage[debugshow]{colortbl}
\makeatletter
\def\notableentry{\cellcolor{blue}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\LARGE
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    alghreaiog & bghsah \\
    \hline
    cagja & \notableentry \\
    \hline
    \cellcolor{blue} & edkhaklgjaj \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: But actually if you are doing this just doing `\hrulefill` is more or less equivalent, and a lot simpler.

Answer (score 5):

You can do that in `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

`nicematrix` creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells of the array and uses them for various functionnalities.

The lastest version (5.1 20/07/31) provides an internal `\g_nicematrix_code_after_tl` for instructions after the construction of the array.

In the following code, I have written a user command `notableentry` which can be used in a cell of the array and which writes instructions in `\g_nicematrix_code_after_tl` to cross the cell with Tikz instructions after the construction of the array.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__pantigny_notableentry:nnn
  {
    \begin { tikzpicture }
    \draw [ #3 ] 
          ( #1 -| \int_eval:n { #2 + 1 } ) 
       -- ( \int_eval:n { #1 + 1 } -| #2 ) 
          ( #1 -| \int_eval:n #2 ) 
       -- ( \int_eval:n { #1 + 1 } -| \int_eval:n { #2 + 1 } ) ; 
    \end { tikzpicture }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \notableentry { ! O { } }
  {
    \tl_gput_right:Nx \g_nicematrix_code_after_tl
      { 
        \__pantigny_notableentry:nnn 
          { \int_use:c { c@iRow } } 
          { \int_use:c { c@jCol } }
          { \exp_not:n { #1 } }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\LARGE
\begin{NiceTabular}{cc}[hvlines,colortbl-like]
    alghreaiog & bghsah \\
    cagja & \notableentry[red] \\
    \cellcolor{blue} & edkhaklgjaj \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\begin{NiceTabular}{p{4cm}p{3cm}}[hvlines,colortbl-like]
    alghreaiog & bghsah \tabularnewline
    cagja\\ bla & \notableentry[red] \tabularnewline
    \cellcolor{blue} & edkhaklgjaj \\ xyz 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

Moreover, the use of the tools provided by `nicematrix` to color the cells gives better results in the PDF viewers than those of `colortbl`.

[image: Output of the above code]