# Make no content cells in a table to be full of parallel black lines

Tags: tables

I have a table and I want to make two cells of it full of parallel lines to show that there is no content in them. How can I do that?

A MWE is the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSDidot.otf}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSDidot.otf}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\everymath{\displaystyle}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
{} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Κινητήρας} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|} {Γεννήτρια}\\
\hline
{} & Y & Δ & Υ & Δ\\
\hline
Cell 1 & $2$ & 2 & $2$ & $2$\\
\hline
Cell 2 & $25.477$ & $25.477$ & {} & {}\\ 
\hline
Cell 3 & $0.9823$ & $0.9765$ & {} & {}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The cells in question are the ones with the `{}`

Edit I: I had forgotten some words in Greek having deleted the code regarding language. I have edited it with these lines of code.

Comment: are you missing inputenc? Or do you assume xelatex  or ??

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156162/strike-out-a-table-cell

Comment: I use xelatex sorry.

Comment: @HenriMenke I want a lot of parallel black lines to mean no content not to cross out the cell.

Comment: @Mico that is the code I use and compile.

Comment: I'd simply center an em-dash or en-dash.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}


%% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\newcommand\zz{\mbox{}\kern-\tabcolsep\cleaders\hbox{\!=\!}\hfill\kern-\tabcolsep\mbox{}}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\everymath{\displaystyle}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
{} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Κινητήρας} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|} {Γεννήτρια}\\
\hline
{} & Y & Δ & Υ & Δ\\
\hline
Cell 1 & $2$ & 2 & $2$ & $2$\\
\hline
Cell 2 & $25.477$ & $25.477$ & \zz & \zz\\ 
\hline
Cell 3 & $0.9823$ & $0.9765$ & \zz & \zz\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A standard technique for indicating that a table cell is either empty or can't have meaningful content is to gray it out, i.e., to fill it in completely with a shade of gray. To do so in XeLaTeX, you could load the `colortbl` and `xcolor` packages and apply the instruction `\cellcolor{gray}` in the cells in question. If "gray" isn't dark enough, you could employ "darkgray", say.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSDidot.otf}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSDidot.otf}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % load colortbl and xcolor packages
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\cellcolor{gray} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Κινητήρας} & \multicolumn{2}{c|} {Γεννήτρια}\\
\hline
\cellcolor{gray} & Y & Δ & Υ & Δ\\
\hline
Cell 1 & $2$ & 2 & $2$ & $2$\\
\hline
Cell 2 & $25.477$ & $25.477$ & \cellcolor{gray} & \cellcolor{gray}\\ 
\hline
Cell 3 & $0.9823$ & $0.9765$ & \cellcolor{gray} & \cellcolor{gray}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my first take. It's not ideal because the length of the lines is hard coded as `4em` at the moment and I would prefer to have this done automatically. Mabybe some TeXpert can improve on this. Otherwise it's quite simple.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}


\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\def\l{\hbox{\vrule width 4em height 0.4pt}\kern1.8pt}
\def\x{\vbox{\kern4pt\l\l\l\l\l}}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
{} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{One} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|} {Two}\\
\hline
{} & Y & $\Delta$ & Υ & $\Delta$ \\
\hline
Cell 1 & $2$ & 2 & $2$ & $2$\\
\hline
Cell 2 & $25.477$ & $25.477$ & \x & \x\\ 
\hline
Cell 3 & $0.9823$ & $0.9765$ & \x & \x\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]