# Cross out arbitrary table cells with diagonal line

Tags: tables

I'm looking for a way to use a diagonal line to cross out a table cell which may or may not be empty, and without having to manually specify the cell's width and height.  (It would also be great if the solution were compatible with tabu.)

That is, I want to find a definition of `\strike` such that the following code produces the following output:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabu}
\newcommand{\strike}[1]{#1} % Some LaTeX wizardry here

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabu}{|[3pt]c|c|c|[3pt]}
\tabucline[3pt]{-}
foo & bar & baz \\
\hline
\strike{quux} & A & B \\
\hline
C & D & \strike{$\delta$} \\
\tabucline[3pt]{-}
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output showing crossed-out table cells]

(I've found several previous Stack Exchange questions on diagonal lines through cells, but they all assume that the cell is of known dimensions, or that the cell is empty, or that the intention is to split the cell into two triangular cells with separate content. The ["Strike out a table cell"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156162/strike-out-a-table-cell) question is probably closest to what I want, except that it's about striking out blank cells; it's not obvious to me how to adapt the solutions to striking out cells which already have content.)

Comment: Is it OK if we suggest a `tikz` alternative?

Comment: Sure, I don't care whether or not the solution uses `tikz`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adapting from the answer you have linked I defined `\strike`. The command takes two arguments, which is due to the varying rules in your table.

```
\strike{<column spec>}{<content>}
```

where `<column spec>` is the column format expected by `\multicolumn`, e.g. `|[3pt]c|`. You may specify columns different from `c`, but this will have no effect due to `\hspace{0pt plus 1filll}` on both sides of the content.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\usepackage{tabu}

\newcounter{NoTableEntry}
\renewcommand*{\theNoTableEntry}{NTE-\the\value{NoTableEntry}}

\newcommand*{\strike}[2]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{#1}{%
    \stepcounter{NoTableEntry}%
    \vadjust pre{\zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry t}}% top
    \vadjust{\zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry b}}% bottom
    \zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry l}% left
    \hspace{0pt plus 1filll}%
    #2% content
    \hspace{0pt plus 1filll}%
    \zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry r}% right
    \tikz[overlay]{%
      \draw
        let
          \n{llx}={\zposx{\theNoTableEntry l}sp-\zposx{\theNoTableEntry r}sp-\tabcolsep},
          \n{urx}={\tabcolsep},
          \n{lly}={\zposy{\theNoTableEntry b}sp-\zposy{\theNoTableEntry r}sp},
          \n{ury}={\zposy{\theNoTableEntry t}sp-\zposy{\theNoTableEntry r}sp}
        in
        (\n{llx}, \n{lly}) -- (\n{urx}, \n{ury})
      ;
    }% 
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabu}{|[3pt]c|c|c|[3pt]}
  \tabucline[3pt]{-}
  foo & bar & baz \\
  \hline
  \strike{|[3pt]c|}{quux} & A & B \\
  \hline
  C & D & \strike{c|[3pt]}{$\delta$} \\
  \tabucline[3pt]{-}
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: This is very nice! What does `\vadjust pre` do? What is the `pre`?

Comment: @cfr It is a pdfTeX extension. From the manual: “The `\vadjust` implementation of pdfTeX adds an optional qualifier `⟨pre spec⟩` (which is the string `pre`) to the original TeX primitive with the same name. As long as there is no `pre` given, `\vadjust` behaves exactly as the original (see the TeXbook, p. 281); it appends an adjustment item created from `⟨vertical mode material⟩` to the current list after the line in which  `\vadjust` appears. However with the qualifier `pre` , the adjustment item is put before the line in which `\vadjust pre` appears.”

Comment: Thank you very much! I was not sure where to find information about the `pre` as I didn't realise it was a pdfTeX enhancement, so I really appreciate your taking the trouble to comment. Your code is proving most useful, but I like to understand what I'm doing ;).

Comment: @cfr Thanks for the compliment, but actually this is not my code.  I just adapted it from a [solution by Heiko](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156172/10995) to a [question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156162/strike-out-a-table-cell).

Comment: @HenriMenke is it possible to color a cell that is crossed out with your code? I tried it with \cellcolor an \rowcolor, but the cell which is crossed out stays always half white...

Comment: @Katharina You should post your comment as a fresh question. [Follow-up questions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117) like this are more than welcome! Please use the "[Ask Question](//tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background.  Also, do not forget to add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @HenriMenke Your solution works but if i use the solution inside a \multicolumn cell itself, then it gives the error Missing \omit. [Detailed example in this open question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/632317/latex-misplaced-omit-for-inside-table-cell-crossout).

Answer (score 3):

This answer shows that, in `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, it's easy to define such command `\strike`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__psychonaut_strike:nn
  { \tikz \draw ( #1 -| \int_eval:n { #2 + 1 } ) -- ( \int_eval:n { #1 + 1 } -| #2 ) ; }

\NewDocumentCommand \strike { }
  {
    \tl_gput_right:Nx \g_nicematrix_code_after_tl
      {
        \__psychonaut_strike:nn
          { \int_use:c { c@iRow } }
          { \int_use:c { c@jCol } }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}[hvlines]
  foo & bar & baz \\
  \strike quux & A & B \\
  C & D & \strike $\delta$ \\
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw [very thick] (1-|1) rectangle (last-|last) ; 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

I have drawn the heavy frame around the tabular with a Tikz instruction in the `\CodeAfter` of the environment because, with `{NiceTabular}`, it's probably the easiest way.

[image: Output of the above code]

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

Answer (score -1):

Modifying [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17745/diagonal-lines-in-table-cell)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\diag[4]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{p{#2}|}{\hskip-\tabcolsep
  $\vcenter{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0,anchor=south west,inner sep=#1]
  \path[use as bounding box] (0,0) rectangle (#2+2\tabcolsep,\baselineskip);
  \node[minimum width={#2+2\tabcolsep},minimum height=\baselineskip+\extrarowheight] (box) {};
  \draw (box.south west) -- (box.north east);
  \node[anchor=south west] at (box.south west) {#3};
  \node[anchor=north east] at (box.north east) {#4};
 \end{tikzpicture}}$\hskip-\tabcolsep}}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{0.1cm}
\begin{tabular}{|x{0.5cm}|x{0.5cm}|x{0.5cm}|x{0.5cm}|x{0.5cm}|}\hline
&&&&20\\ \hline
&&&&30\\ \hline
&&&&45\\ \hline
15&12&18&50&\diag{.1em}{.5cm}{$a_i$}{$b_j$}\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer my question.  This code uses a fixed cell size, and splits cell into two areas of separate content.