# How to color crossed out cell?

Tags: tikz-pgf, colortbl

I crossed out the letter K using the answer given here... [cross out arbitrary cells](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223420/cross-out-arbitrary-table-cells-with-diagonal-line) Then I colored the row using `\cellcolor`, but the cell, which is crossed out is only half filled... What do I need to change to color the whole cell...?

[image]

This is my code...

```
\documentclass[titlepage=true, 12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[L]{Name}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{tabularx}


\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{zref-savepos}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor,stackengine}

\newcommand\splat[3][white]{%
  \colorbox{#1}{~~\sffamily\stackon{\fbox{\makebox[3ex]{\large\strut #2}}}{#3}~~}%
}

\usepackage{colortbl}

\newcounter{NoTableEntry}
\renewcommand*{\theNoTableEntry}{NTE-\the\value{NoTableEntry}}

\newcommand*{\strike}[2]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{#1}{%
    \stepcounter{NoTableEntry}%
    \vadjust pre{\zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry t}}% top
    \vadjust{\zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry b}}% bottom
    \zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry l}% left
    \hspace{0pt plus 1filll}%
    #2% content
    \hspace{0pt plus 1filll}%
    \zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry r}% right
    \tikz[overlay]{%
      \draw
        let
          \n{llx}={\zposx{\theNoTableEntry l}sp-\zposx{\theNoTableEntry r}sp-\tabcolsep},
          \n{urx}={\tabcolsep},
          \n{lly}={\zposy{\theNoTableEntry b}sp-\zposy{\theNoTableEntry r}sp},
          \n{ury}={\zposy{\theNoTableEntry t}sp-\zposy{\theNoTableEntry r}sp}
        in
        (\n{llx}, \n{lly}) -- (\n{urx}, \n{ury})
      ;
    }% 
  }%
}




    \begin{document}

    \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{5pt}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{6pt}

    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.63\textwidth}

    \begin{tabular}{|C{0.8cm}|L{8cm}|}

    \hline
    A & peu de cours \\
    \hline
    B &  la confiance en soi\\
    \hline
    C &  se trouve le village du Père Noël \\
    \hline
    D & début de semestre\\
    \hline
    E &  à augmenter la fréquentation de la ville\\
    \hline
    F & des ours polaires \\
    \hline
    G & fin de semestre\\
    \hline
    H & beaucoup de cours \\
    \hline
    I & nous a permis de nous intégrer plus facilement \\
    \hline
    J & une magnifique aurore boréale \\
    \hline
    \strike{|c|}{\cellcolor{gray!30}K} &\cellcolor{gray!30} les gens sont quasiment tous bilingues en anglais \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \end{minipage}}
    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.36\textwidth}

    \Shortstack[l]{
    \splat[gray!30]{K}{0}\splat{}{1}\splat{}{2}\splat{}{3}
    \splat{}{4}\splat{}{5}\splat{}{6}\splat{}{7}
    \splat{}{8}}

    \end{minipage}}


    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to, instead of using `\strike`, use the `\cancel` feature of the `cancel` package.  The only quirk is that it operates in math mode, so I needed to use `$\cancel{\mbox{K}}$`.

```
\documentclass[titlepage=true, 12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath,cancel}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[L]{Name}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{tabularx}


\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{zref-savepos}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor,stackengine}

\newcommand\splat[3][white]{%
  \colorbox{#1}{~~\sffamily\stackon{\fbox{\makebox[3ex]{\large\strut #2}}}{#3}~~}%
}

\usepackage{colortbl}

\newcounter{NoTableEntry}
\renewcommand*{\theNoTableEntry}{NTE-\the\value{NoTableEntry}}

\newcommand*{\strike}[2]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{#1}{%
    \stepcounter{NoTableEntry}%
    \vadjust pre{\zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry t}}% top
    \vadjust{\zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry b}}% bottom
    \zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry l}% left
    \hspace{0pt plus 1filll}%
    #2% content
    \hspace{0pt plus 1filll}%
    \zsavepos{\theNoTableEntry r}% right
    \tikz[overlay]{%
      \draw
        let
          \n{llx}={\zposx{\theNoTableEntry l}sp-\zposx{\theNoTableEntry r}sp-\tabcolsep},
          \n{urx}={\tabcolsep},
          \n{lly}={\zposy{\theNoTableEntry b}sp-\zposy{\theNoTableEntry r}sp},
          \n{ury}={\zposy{\theNoTableEntry t}sp-\zposy{\theNoTableEntry r}sp}
        in
        (\n{llx}, \n{lly}) -- (\n{urx}, \n{ury})
      ;
    }% 
  }%
}




    \begin{document}

    \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{5pt}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{6pt}

    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.63\textwidth}

    \begin{tabular}{|C{0.8cm}|L{8cm}|}

    \hline
    A & peu de cours \\
    \hline
    B &  la confiance en soi\\
    \hline
    C &  se trouve le village du Père Noël \\
    \hline
    D & début de semestre\\
    \hline
    E &  à augmenter la fréquentation de la ville\\
    \hline
    F & des ours polaires \\
    \hline
    G & fin de semestre\\
    \hline
    H & beaucoup de cours \\
    \hline
    I & nous a permis de nous intégrer plus facilement \\
    \hline
    J & une magnifique aurore boréale \\
    \hline
    \cellcolor{gray!30}$\cancel{\mbox{K}}$ &\cellcolor{gray!30} les gens sont quasiment tous bilingues en anglais \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \end{minipage}}
    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.36\textwidth}

    \Shortstack[l]{
    \splat[gray!30]{K}{0}\splat{}{1}\splat{}{2}\splat{}{3}
    \splat{}{4}\splat{}{5}\splat{}{6}\splat{}{7}
    \splat{}{8}}

    \end{minipage}}


    \end{document}
```

[image]

One can then play games to fudge it:

```
\hline
\cellcolor{gray!30}\makebox[0pt]{$\cancel{\makebox[5.7ex]{%
  K\rule[-3ex]{0pt}{5.5ex}}}$} &%
  \cellcolor{gray!30} les gens sont quasiment tous bilingues en anglais \\
\hline
```

Here is the result

[image]

Comment: Steven Hi. I have voted two your answer +2! Excellent.

Comment: @Sebastiano And you deserve a +2 for your enthusiasm for LaTeX.

Comment: AHAHAH. :-) I just saw but did not have to return the +2. You run, like so many others, that I know a lot and excellent work. I voted positively because they are done very well.

Comment: @Sebastiano The desire to encourage others is a great virtue.  I can always count on you for such encouragement.  It is infectious.

Comment: Your solution works really well, but one of the advantages of \strike is, that the the lign is automatically adjusted to the width and height of the cell, so you don't have to play around every time, which can be quite time consuming if you need to use that code a lot... Is there a way to change it, so that the line adjust itself?

Comment: @Katharina There is no easy fix.  The width is approximately the width of "K" plus `2\tabcolsep`.  The height is approximately `2\normalbaselineskip` plus a few points (unless you have modified `\arraystretch`).

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes thank you for that tipp! I inserted two \ spaces before and after the K and now the whole cell is gray :)

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you can easily draw whatever rule you want in your tabular with TikZ because `nicematrix` creates PGF/TikZ nodes under the cells, rows and columns of the tabular for you.

Here, the instruction to strike your cell is
`\tikz \draw (12-|1) -- (11-|2) ;`
in the `\CodeAfter` of the environment `{NiceTabular}`.

```
\documentclass[titlepage=true, 12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\newcommand\splat[3][white]{%
  \colorbox{#1}{~~\sffamily\stackon{\fbox{\makebox[3ex]{\large\strut #2}}}{#3}~~}%
}


\begin{document}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{5pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{6pt}

\adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.63\textwidth}
\begin{NiceTabular}{p[c]{0.8cm}p[l]{8cm}}[hvlines,color-inside]
    A & peu de cours \\
    B & la confiance en soi\\
    C & se trouve le village du Père Noël \\
    D & début de semestre\\
    E & à augmenter la fréquentation de la ville\\
    F & des ours polaires \\
    G & fin de semestre\\
    H & beaucoup de cours \\
    I & nous a permis de nous intégrer plus facilement \\
    J & une magnifique aurore boréale \\
    \rowcolor{gray!30}
    K & les gens sont quasiment tous bilingues en anglais \\
\CodeAfter
    \tikz \draw (12-|1) -- (11-|2) ; 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{minipage}}
%
\adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.36\textwidth}
\Shortstack[l]{
\splat[gray!30]{K}{0}\splat{}{1}\splat{}{2}\splat{}{3}
\splat{}{4}\splat{}{5}\splat{}{6}\splat{}{7}
\splat{}{8}}
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]