# Cross covers entire cell in tabular

Tags: tables

How to draw a cross so that it covers the entire cell in tabular environment?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lc}
\hline
\texttimes & some thing\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [Cross out arbitrary table cells with diagonal line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/223420/5764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[12pt, french]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{diagbox, xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}%
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\diagbox[innerwidth=\dimexpr1em+\arrayrulewidth, height=\dimexpr\line+0.5 \arrayrulewidth , dir=SW]{}{}} \\[-2.9ex]
\hline
\diagbox[innerwidth=1em, height=\line]{}{}
 & Some thing \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]