# Strike out a cell - how to extend this solution for tabularray package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tabularray

[This solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156172/16782) is exactly what I'm going for, but unfortunately the `tabularray` package removes the ability to use multicolumn and I cannot therefore get any of the solutions to work.

I tried just replacing the multicolumn command with Tabularray's `\SetCell`, but that was unsuccessful.

Would love some assist modifying the original solution or something different to achieve the same result (ideally still using tabularray as the base, but if I really can't, I can consider switching to other table packages for this table).

Here is an example table with the cell to strike through indicated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
   colspec = {Q[l,m,2in]*{2}{Q[c,m]}},
   hlines,
   vlines
}
Testing a cell & Test & More text\\
Another row & & \\
\SetRow{ht=1.5in}{Strike this cell out with an X\\from bottom-left to top-right\\and top-left to bottom-right\\may have more than one row\\or altered height} & & \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems like another task for [tag:nicematrix].

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I did consider it, but every other table is built with tabularray (working on a very large project), so I'm hoping I don't have to use a different table setup just for this one need.

Answer (score 5):

This is a solution using `nicematrix`:

(1) Emulate the table using the `nicematrix` package.

The command `\Block` command creates a 9x1 multi-row/column cell. It doesn't create space, so empty rows were added. `\\` is allowed inside `\Block`.

(2) The package creates `Tikz` nodes in the cells of the matrix.

The `\CodeAfter` command can be used to place some code that will be executed after construction
of the matrix. With the `tikz` package loaded it is
possible to draw the red lines between the corners of the Block.

[image: d]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\usepackage{nicematrix} % added <<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{tikz}% added <<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tblr}{
            colspec = {Q[l,m,2in]*{2}{Q[c,m]}},
            hlines,
            vlines
        }
        Testing a cell & Test & More text\\
        Another row & & \\
        \SetRow{ht=1.5in}{Strike this cell out with an X\\from bottom-left to top-right\\and top-left to bottom-right\\may have more than one row\\or altered height} & & \\
    \end{tblr}
    
    \bigskip
    
    Using nicematrix:
    
    \medskip
    
    \begin{NiceTabular}{W{l}{2in}cc}[vlines,cell-space-top-limit=4pt, cell-space-bottom-limit=1pt] % vertical lines, expand the cells vertically
        \hline
        Testing a cell & Test & More text\\\hline
        Another row & & \\\hline
        \Block[l]{9-1}{Strike this cell out with an X\\from bottom-left to top-right\\and top-left to bottom-right\\may have more than one row\\or altered height} & & \\
        &&\\ % create space for the Block
        &&\\
        &&\\
        &&\\
        &&\\
        &&\\
        &&\\
        &&\\
        \hline
        \CodeAfter % draw a red X
        \tikz \draw [thick,red](3-|1) -- (last-|2)  ;
        \tikz \draw [thick,red](3-|2) -- (last-|1)  ;
    \end{NiceTabular}   
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I can’t resolve it using tabularray, I will have to go this route.

Comment: Interesting workaround to `ht = 1.5in`, I tried myself (never used the package myself) and was hoping for something like `\Block[height = 1.5in]{1-1}{…}`. It's unfortunate that `tblr` produces a nice output out of the box where we need `cell-space-limits` here and then the first row is taller than the second because of the `g` in the first one.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thank you for your comments. You are right, a height parameter is missing from this package. Or `tabularray` needs to allow execution of tikz commands

Answer (score 0):

Following the comments of Qrrbrbirlbel to Simon Dispa's answer (+1), I add another answer with `nicematrix`.

In that solution, I have created a row of total height (`\ht`+`\dp`) equal to 1.5 in by adding a strut : `\rule[-0.75in]{0pt}{1.5in}`.

In have also drawn the red cross in the `\CodeBefore` in order to have a perfect output in the corners.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tblr}{
        colspec = {Q[l,m,2in]*{2}{Q[c,m]}},
        hlines,
        vlines
    }
    Testing a cell & Test & More text\\
    Another row & & \\
    \SetRow{ht=1.5in}{Strike this cell out with an X\\from bottom-left to top-right\\and top-left to bottom-right\\may have more than one row\\or altered height} & & \\
\end{tblr}

\bigskip

Using \verb|nicematrix|:

\medskip

\begin{NiceTabular}{W{l}{2in}cc}[hvlines] 
\CodeBefore
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip (3-|1) rectangle (last-|2) ; 
    \draw [thick,red] (3-|1) -- (last-|2) (3-|2) -- (last-|1) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\Body
Testing a cell & Test & More text\\
Another row \\
\rule[-0.75in]{0pt}{1.5in}
\Block[v-center]{}{Strike this cell out with an X\\from bottom-left to top-right\\and top-left to bottom-right\\may have more than one row\\or altered height} & & \\
\end{NiceTabular}   
    
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

A zoom on a corner:

[image: Zoom on a corner]

For the first and the second rows, the spaces above and below the lines of text are exactly the sames as with `{tabular}` (by design of `nicematrix`).

It's possible to increase those spaces by using (for instance) `\arraystretch`.