# Latex - Create Concept Matrix with two dimensions

Tags: tables, matrices

I am trying to create a concept matrix in latex that sticks with the following scheme:

[image]

Is this possible to achieve? Do you have any starting points for such-alike table?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try **Excel2LaTeX** for such a complicated table.

Comment: This is fairly a straight-forward table except for the very 1st cell with a diagonal cut. For such diagonal cut, you may follow [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/553721/219947).

Comment: @Imran thank you for the reference, will look into that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As starting point first few table rows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{rotating}   % needed
\usepackage{makecell}   % needed

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
%\NewTableCommand\TB{\textbullet}
\newcommand\TB{\textbullet}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\settowidth\rotheadsize{Proneness to human error}    % from makecell
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z} = 1pt,
             hline{2-Y}=solid, vlines,
             colspec = {l *{11}{c}}, 
             cell{2}{2-Z} = {cmd=\rotcell},
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries}
            }
\SetCell[r=2]{f, font=\bfseries}    Articles
    &   \SetCell[c=11]{c}   Characteristic
        &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &       \\
    & text
        & text
            & text
                & text
                    & text
                        & Proneness to human error
                            & text
                                & text
                                    & text
                                        & text
                                            & text  \\
\cite{10}
    &   & \TB 
            & \TB
                &   &   &   & \TB  
                                & \TB
                                    & \TB
                                        &   &       \\
\cite{3}
    &  \TB
        &   & \TB
                &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &       \\
\cite{9}
    &  \TB
        & \TB 
            & \TB
                &   &   & \TB  
                            &   &   &   &   &       \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Zarko, this did the trick! :-)

Comment: do you know how to vertically align the "dots" in the cell in case the references spread over several lines?

Comment: @bpmler, sorry for late response. I do not completely understand what you mean. Please editi your question and show me an example what you  mean with your comment. I guess that it may help the following change in table preamble: `colspec = {X[l, m] *{11}{c}},`, however, now table width will become equal to text width. Id this desired to?

Comment: no worries, this is already fixed - thank you anway! :-)