# Creating table as shown in the picture

Tags: tables

I want to create a table in LaTeX which begins as shown in the figure below. How do I make it using the table/tabular package? I made it using TikZ, but I am sure this is not the efficient way to go about.

[image]

Comment: See whether you can modify the solutions here for your table: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17745/diagonal-lines-in-table-cell

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9253/slashbox-alternative/

Comment: Oops, just saw that the answers in the question I linked were all TiKz, which you said you used...my bad.  Good that Torbjorn had you covered.